# C# Entity Framework: Bulk Update with Where and Join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

How do I update Certain records in with Join and Where clause in Entity Framework Core? Using the template answer below (Attach/isModified)?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247720/12425844

"If you don't want to use an SQL statement, you can use the Attach method in order to update an entity without having to load it first. As it's attached as Unchanged by default. You need to call make `isModified = true`"

**Current requirement:**

```
var data = _dbContext.Set<Product>()
    .Include(c => c.ProductType)
    .Where(x => x.Manufacturer == "ABC Company" &&
                x.StartYear == 2019 &&
                x.ProductType.ProductTypeDescription == "Electronics")

data.Manufacturer = "XYZ Company";
data.StartYear = 2020;
_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Goal Code:**
Have to add where and join to find particular records:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247720/12425844

```
using (myDbEntities db = new myDbEntities())
{
    try
    {
      db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

      MyObjectEntity entityToUpdate = new MyObjectEntity() {Manufacturer = "XYZ Company", StartYear =2020};
      db.Entry(entityToUpdate).Property(e => e.Manufacturer).IsModified = true;
      db.Entry(entityToUpdate).Property(e => e.StartYear).IsModified = true;

      db.SaveChanges();
    }
    finally
    {
      db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Using EF Net Core 3.1 ,

Will not accept answers using Raw sql or EF Extensions for now, just Native EF Core

Comment: EF Core only tracks changes to individual items, and has no method to generate bulk updates. So you're going to have to allow some other answer.

Comment: hi @JeremyLakeman so I can only update All the records in the database, no where clause?

Comment: Fundamentally, SaveChanges generates update statements based on the primary keys of individual objects that were attached to the change tracker. So you'd need to load all the objects, change the values, then save. Which is clearly inefficient.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman ok, I thought this answer would avoid all this? it avoids change tracking and prevents loading all the entities https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247720/12425844

Comment: If you know the primary keys of all the rows you want to update, yes you can attach them to the context without loading them. If you don't, well EF Core doesn't support generating sql for "bulk updates".

Comment: ok @JeremyLakeman seems contrary to the resource, which does not mention that, and is updating by nonprimary key values

Comment: Without changing the property `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` just get the records and update the values for it and directly call `SaveChanges()` method, that should update the records in the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If EF Extensions is out, what about [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)?

```cs
await _dbContext.Set<Product>()
    .Where(x => x.Manufacturer == "ABC Company" &&
                x.StartYear == 2019 &&
                x.ProductType.ProductTypeDescription == "Electronics")
    .BatchUpdateAsync(x => new Product(){
                Manufacturer = "XYZ Company",
                StartYear = 2020 });
```

Note update is performed as raw sql, objects loaded into the change tracker are not updated. You may wish to surround the bulk operations and `SaveChangesAsync` in a transaction.

YMMV, I haven't used this library myself.

Comment: I am only allowing Native EF core solutions and said in question, no extensions, thanks

Comment: The license is MIT, so you are free to copy-paste the source code.

Comment: While I could read the `BulkExtensions` source code and explain how it works in an SO answer, the problem you want to solve is complicated. Someone else has already solved it. They have allowed you to use and distribute their solution for free. So, I'd do that.

Comment: hi, I have follow up question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63514362/c-sharp-entity-framework-update-only-first-batch-records-and-stop  thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

#### Native .EF Core 7.0+ solution:

For those using EF Core 7.0 or higher, you can now use the new `ExecuteUpdate` method to achieve exactly this — to use OP's example:

```cs
_dbContext.Set<Product>()
    .Include(c => c.ProductType)
    .Where(x => x.Manufacturer == "ABC Company" &&
                x.StartYear == 2019 &&
                x.ProductType.ProductTypeDescription == "Electronics")
    .ExecuteUpdate(x => x
        .SetProperty(p => p.Manufacturer, "XYZ Company")
        .SetProperty(p => p.StartYear, "2020"));
```

This will generate the right `UPDATE` SQL statement. For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74208246/7734384), and the official blog post ["What's new in EF Core 7.0?"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates)