# C# Entity Framework: Update Only First Batch Records and Stop

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there way with EF Core Bulk extensions to only update first few 10000 rows? write message, update next batch, write message in loop until complete?

I know there is Batch Size, however if there is only 5 million to update, and I want only update a certain amount, write a message, in continual loop until complete, how can this be done?

Should I use Top or Take?

I want to write "Hello", every few batches.

```
while {

await _dbContext.Set<Product>()
    .Where(x => x.Manufacturer == "ABC Company" &&
                x.StartYear == 2019 &&
                x.ProductType.ProductTypeDescription == "Electronics")
    .BatchUpdateAsync(x => new Product(){
                Manufacturer = "XYZ Company",
                StartYear = 2020 });

Console.WriteLine("hello"):
```

https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Using EF Core 3.1.

Company does not want to use SignalR

Comment: With sql like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903375/how-to-update-large-table-with-millions-of-rows-in-sql-server/35931214? BatchUpdateAsync returns the rowcount, so you could surround with `$"SET rowcount {n}"` raw sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like BatchSize is only used for bulk insert.  For update the expression is translated to a single SQL UPDATE statement, which doesn't operate by "batches".

Comment: hi David, I have a question here, thanks , currently using AzureSql https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/274411/update-large-table-with-millions-of-rows-in-sql-server-in-parallel

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

### if loop until first few 10,000

```
int iEnd = 5;

for (var i = 0; i <= iEnd; i++)
{
    var products = await _dbContext.Set<Product>().Where(x => x.Manufacturer == "ABC Company" &&
                    x.StartYear == 2019 &&
                    x.ProductType.ProductTypeDescription == "Electronics").Skip(i * 10000).Take(10000).ToList();

    products.ForEach(x =>
    {
         x.Manufacturer = "XYZ Company";
         x.StartYear = 2020;
    });
    _dbContext.Set<Product>().UpdateRange(products); // or you can use BulkUpdate here.
}

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

### If loop until 5 millions.

```
int i = 0;
Boolean IsContinue = true;
while (IsContinue)
{
     var products = await _dbContext.Set<Product>().Where(x => x.Manufacturer == "ABC Company" &&
                x.StartYear == 2019 &&
                x.ProductType.ProductTypeDescription == "Electronics").Skip(i * 10000).Take(10000).ToList();

     if (products.Count() == 0)
          IsContinue = false;
     else
     {
          products.ForEach(x =>
          {
                x.Manufacturer = "XYZ Company";
                x.StartYear = 2020;
          });
          _dbContext.Set<Product>().UpdateRange(products); // or you can use BulkUpdate here.
      }
      i++;
}

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```