# How to update list without using for loop in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Original Oracle SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET col1 = '1', col2 = '2' 
WHERE col3 = '3';
```

Entity Framework:

```
var updateData = DbContext.Table1.Where(x => x.col3 == "3");

foreach (var item in updateData)
{
    item.col1 = "1";
    item.col2 = "2";
}

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But I found that it would take a lot time if there are many records in `updateData`.

I tried output the SQL as below and found that entity framework will update each data in `updateData`, if there are 100 records in `updateData`, then the script as below will show up 100 times and it will need take 175 ms * 100 to update data.

```
update "Table1"
set "col1" = :p0,"col2" = :p1
where (((("Col3" = :p2)) and ("Col4" = :p3))
-- :p0: '1' 
-- :p1: '2' 
-- :p2: '3' 
-- :p3: 'otherData..'
-- Executing at 2021/4/14 08:20:07 +08:00
-- Completed in 175 ms with result: 1
```

Is there any better way to update list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194877/how-to-bulk-update-records-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with EF, only by pure SQL or Stored Procedure. But there are third party extensions which can do that for you. For example https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore (disclaimer, I'm one of the creators)

Then you can run the following:

```cs
DbContext.Table1.Where(x => x.col3 == "3")
  .Set(x => x.col1, "1")
  .Set(x => x.col2, "2")
  .Update();
```